# Comma in request payload cause error on POST request from angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, rest

I'm doing a POST request to an external service from an Angular App.
This is the Request Paylod ( from chrome console )
[image]

as you can see, there is a comma in one of the body field and for this reason I'm getting this error: ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION.
I search on the internet and I found that you need to use double quotes to resolve the problem but, as you can see, the value of field contentName is already between double quotes. I also tried to do the same request from Postman and everything works fine (the reqeust from the postman console looks exactly the same of the chrome console ).  I'm facing this problem only when I use Chrome or Edge, in Firefox everything works. 
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: These commas are contained within double quotes, so they should not be a problem. Examine the headers carefully, and also look at the raw request.

Comment: @php_nub_qq nope, the headers looks fine ( no commas )